# Font Awesome works on one component but not on the other one in Angular

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome

I am working on an existing project in Angular. I have added a component a month ago, which is form with some inputs. I also have some Font Awesome icons which are displaying nicely. Code below.

```html
<div class="field">
        <p class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
          <input type="text"
          class="input"
          id="title"
          required
          placeholder="Title"
          [(ngModel)]="model.title"
          name="title"
          #title="ngModel">
          <span class="icon is-small is-left">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          </span>
        </p>
  </div>
```

Then I have another component which is consisted of some cards. I tried to insert icons as well, but they don't show. Instead I always get a small rectangle, no matter what I try or where I insert the icon.

```html
<section class="section" *ngFor="let campaign of dummyCampaigns">
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpMdM.png" alt="Location map">
      <div class="course-details">
          <p class="date">
              Starting {{ campaign.startDate }}
          </p>
          <p class="price">
              Ending {{ campaign.endDate }}
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="separator"></div>

  <div class="course-info">
      <p class="title">{{ campaign.title }}</p>
      <p class="sub-title">{{ campaign.owner}}</p>
      <div class="title-separator"></div>
      <div class="toggle">
          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      </div>
      <!--><a href="#" class="more-info">More info</a><-->
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Any idea why would icons work in one Angular component and not in the other one?

Answer (score 1):

Is FontAwesomeModule correctly imported so it can be used by the other component?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check on this? For the first component (in which it works) I never made any special imports, as well as for the second component. Since it's existing project, imports have been sorted long time ago.

Comment: Just search for FontAwesomeModule in your project and see where it is imported. If it is not imported in app.module.ts you can simply import it there and every component should be able to use it.

Comment: I went to check how it is actually imported and found out import is in angular.json. It was imported in "styles" but not in "scripts" so I just added path to "scripts" like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801612/14089282

Answer (score 0):

Path for import existed in "styles" but was missing from "scripts". After I added path to "scripts" it works. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58801612/14089282)